# Releasing ivars and setting properties to nil in Apple documentation

Tags: ios

I have always used the `@synthesize` with a class properties declared in the .h file. I came across the *PhotoPicker* example in some Apple docs [found here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Listings/AppDelegate_m.html) and found a really confusing declaration. In their AppDelegate class (.h file) they don't create any ivars, just properties, like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@end
```

And in their Appdelegate.m file they write this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate;
```

Now, I don't find any `@synthesize` directives, or any ivars, however if I look at the `dealloc` method they release some "invisible" ivars (What???)

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_navController release];
    [_window release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

And in the viewController classes, they set the properties to nil in `viewDidUnload` and release the (non-created) "ivars" in the `dealloc` method.

Does this have to do with some new Xcode thing? Can someone shed some light into this? I was checking my logic on `didReceiveMemoryWarning`and always have set the properties to nil in `viewDidUnload`and releasing the ivars in `dealloc`but I hadn't seen this before.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are you using iOS(5 or above) sdk ??                                      I think xcode do it automatically for us and this feature is introduced with iOS 5.

Comment: the @synthesise line is automatic generated with XCode 4.5 for properties

Comment: Yes, the example is using iOS 5.0 SDK, but let's say i want to target iOS 4.3, should I also release an ivar even if I didn't declare one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 4.5 can autosynthesize properties. It does so by creating the normal setter/getter, and also creates an ivar with a prepended '_'. If you do not like that, you can add your own:

```
@synthesize foo;
```

or use whatever ivar you want:

```
@synthesize foo=MyFoo;
```

These issues of properties and synthesize is orthogonal to memory management. If you have ARC, and of the above techniques just work - you don't need to use dealloc. However, if you do not use arc, then you should release objects in dealloc using [_foo release];

The reason release is recommended over say self.foo = nil, is that using the setter will generate KVO notifications after your object has formally been released.

Comment: just to be clear. In my code, I don't use ARC, but it still creates the ivar prepended with '_', so I should set the property to nil in `viewDidUnload`and release it in `dealloc` or one of the two is enough?

Comment: Ok, for whatever is worth, if I use the `@synthesize`directive i get errors in the dealloc method. So that's that, thank you for the response.

Comment: If you don't use ARC, then provide a dealloc that calls super. If you use @ synthesize, then '[foo release]'. If you don't use @ synthesize, your ivar is named '_foo', so use [_foo release];'